# client side display results of asynchronous tasks [django]

Tags: jquery, django, asynchronous, atom-feed

I'd like to know if there is a better way/pattern of doing what i have in mind.

I have a server side process that executes asyncronous tasks. Am planning to use celery for this. the asynchronous tasks themselves can have sub tasks.
Even though I need to review history of executed tasks and child tasks, I'm not planning to use the celery result backend, but just listen for the task_finished signals and update existing django models I'm using for logs as needed.

**The question is around what is the way to report the status of these tasks to the user?**

So in the web ui, there will be a widget/block of html somewhere where the tasks and their status are listed.
I need to display sub tasks grouped by parent tasks and individual sub task status. On the page, I'd just poll using jquery everytime a task was executed and on some interval.

My thought was to use Atom for this but according to the spec, their are strict rules around what the content element [(link to spec)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#page-14) is allowed to hold. The specific concern is around how i would represent child tasks when using atom.

The other idea is just to use straight up json and parse accordingly.

Does anyone know of a better way/pattern to use for this?

Comment: Would you consider using a long lived http connection to push the status?

Comment: push is definitely preferable. I've never done a long lived http connection implementation before. Is this what you are recommending?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787530/does-django-have-a-way-to-open-a-http-long-poll-connection
I'd like to reduce complexity of the stack by not introducing more server side components than i need, but it doesn't look like i can getaway from needing geventlets or comet if i do a long lived connection