# Is Orbited still active? And Long Polling Code

Tags: python, django, orbited

So my question is if this project is still active? It seems orbited.org is down and I am finding old tutorials or documentation for the orbited project. I want to use this project to run some backend scripts that can take a while to run. That is they are pooling weblogic servers to start, stop, restart.

Should I stick with orbited or is there a better way to do this with django?

Comment: What'd you end up doing? Look at the suggestions I made below at all? I'm curious as to what the best way to do this in Python is, as web results do seem to be equivocal.

Comment: yea thanks for the info. I am still kind of researching. I liked orbited because it was seperate server / js. But havnt seen much else in that realm yet. Twisted looks like id have to make my own server and tornado not sure yet

Comment: This might solve my problem. http://iraniweb.com/blog/?p=56

Answer (score 2):

The top Google results for Orbited are all Summer '09, which seems to be when the last release was made. The last entry on pypi is 0.7.10, in June '09. A Wayback Machine shows the site last crawled in '09 as well.

So yes, it seems the project is dead.

This question: [The latest recommendation for Comet in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514899/the-latest-recommendation-for-comet-in-python) and several pages turned up by a Google search seem to suggest Tornado http://www.tornadoweb.org/ or Twisted http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ as the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are being maintained by separate people at this point, but they both seem to be active. Here are the links to where they are being maintained: [Orbited](https://bitbucket.org/desmaj/orbited), [Orbited2](https://github.com/gameclosure/orbited2)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the project is, indeed, dead:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/orbited-users/MhEIjOxwEKM/I_fMdLGGAJYJ