# Trial unittests using Autobahn WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I'm trying to write unittests for my application that uses Autobahn.

I want to test my controllers which gets received data from protocol, parses it and reacts to it.

But when my test comes to a point when protocol should be disconnected (`self.sendClose`) then it raises error

```
exceptions.AttributeError: 'MyProtocol' object has no attribute 'state'.
```

I was trying to `makeConnection` using `proto_helpers.StringTransport` but then I have errors too

```
exceptions.AttributeError: StringTransport instance has no attribute 'setTcpNoDelay'`
```

I'm using `trial` and I don't want to run dummy server/client for testing purposes only, because it's not recommended.

How should I write my tests so I can test functions that sends data, read data, disconnects etc. using fake connection and trial ?

Comment: Perhaps some of the protocol tests in Autobahn itself can provide inspiration: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/autobahn/websocket/test/test_protocol.py If you provide some more example code it would probably be easier to see what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to say exactly what is going on without having a peek at `MyProtocol` class. The problem sounds a lot like it is caused by the fact that you are directly messing round with low level functions and therefore also the `state` attribute of `WebSocket` class, which is, well, a representation of the internal state of the WebSocket connection.

According to [the autobahn reference doc](https://autobahnpython.readthedocs.org/), the APIs from the `WebSicketProtocol` that you could directly use and override are:

- onOpen
- onMessage
- onClose
- sendMessage
- sendClose

Your approach of using the `StringTransport` to test your protocol is not ideal. The problem lays in the fact that `MyProtocol` is a tiny layer on top of the `WebSocketProtocol` framework provided by autobahn which, for better or worse, hides the details about managing the connection, the transport and the internal protocol state.

If you think about it, you want to test your stuff, not `WebSocketProtocol` and therefore if you do not want to embed a dummy server or client, your best bet is to test directly the methods that `MyProtocol` overrides.

An example of what I am saying is the following

```
class MyPublisher(object):
    cbk=None

    def publish(self, msg):
        if self.cbk:
            self.cbk(msg)

class MyProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def __init__(self, publisher):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.__init__(self)
        #Defining callback for publisher
        publisher.cbk = self.sendMessage

    def onMessage(self, msg, binary)
        #Stupid echo
        self.sendMessage(msg)

class NotificationTest(unittest.TestCase):    

    class MyProtocolFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
        def __init__(self, publisher):
            WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self, "ws://127.0.0.1:8081")
            self.publisher = publisher
            self.openHandshakeTimeout = None

        def buildProtocol(self, addr):
            protocol =  MyProtocol(self.listener)
            protocol.factory = self
            protocol.websocket_version = 13 #Hybi version 13 is supported by pretty much everyone (apart from IE <8 and android browsers)
            return protocol

    def setUp(self):
        publisher = task.LoopingCall(self.send_stuff, "Hi there")        
        factory = NotificationTest.MyProtocolFactory(listener)
        protocol = factory.buildProtocol(None)
        transport = proto_helpers.StringTransport()
        def play_dumb(*args): pass
        setattr(transport, "setTcpNoDelay", play_dumb)
        protocol.makeConnection(transport)
        self.protocol, self.transport, self.publisher, self.fingerprint_handler =  protocol, transport, publisher, fingerprint_handler

    def test_onMessage(self):
        #Following 2 lines are the problematic part. Here you are manipulating explicitly a hidden state which your implementation should not be concerned with!
        self.protocol.state = WebSocketProtocol.STATE_OPEN
        self.protocol.websocket_version = 13
        self.protocol.onMessage("Whatever")
        self.assertEqual(self.transport.value()[2:], 'Whatever')

    def test_push(self):              
        #Following 2 lines are the problematic part. Here you are manipulating explicitly a hidden state which your implementation should not be concerned with!
        self.protocol.state = WebSocketProtocol.STATE_OPEN
        self.protocol.websocket_version = 13
        self.publisher.publish("Hi there")
        self.assertEqual(self.transport.value()[2:], 'Hi There')
```

As you might have noticed, using the `StringTransport` here is very cumbersome. You must have knowledge of the underline framework and bypass its state management, something you don't really want to do. Unfortunately autobahn does not provide a ready-to-use test object that would permit easy state manipulation and therefore my suggestion of using dummy servers and clients is still valid

---

### Testing your server WITH network

The test provided shows how you can test server push, asserting that what your are getting is what you expect, and using also a hook on how to determine when to finish.

### The server protocol

```
from twisted.trial.unittest import TestCase as TrialTest
from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory, connectWS, listenWS
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet import task 

START="START"            

class TestServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def __init__(self):
        #The publisher task simulates an event that triggers a message push
        self.publisher = task.LoopingCall(self.send_stuff, "Hi there")

    def send_stuff(self, msg):
        #this method sends a message to the client
        self.sendMessage(msg)

    def _on_start(self):
        #here we trigger the task to execute every second
        self.publisher.start(1.0)

    def onMessage(self, message, binary):
        #According to this stupid protocol, the server starts sending stuff when the client sends a "START" message
        #You can plug other commands in here
        {
           START : self._on_start
           #Put other keys here
        }[message]()

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        #After closing the connection, we tell the task to stop sending messages
        self.publisher.stop()
```

### The client protocol and factory

Next class is the client protocol. It basically tells the server to start pushing messages. It calls the `close_condition` on them to see if it is time to close the connection and as a last thing, it calls the `assertion` function on the messages it received to see if the test was successful or not

```
class TestClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def __init__(self, assertion, close_condition, timeout, *args, **kwargs):
        self.assertion = assertion
        self.close_condition = close_condition
        self._received_msgs = [] 
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        #This is a way to set a timeout for your test 
        #in case you never meet the conditions dictated by close_condition
        self.damocle_sword = reactor.callLater(timeout, self.sendClose)

    def onOpen(self):
        #After the connection has been established, 
        #you can tell the server to send its stuff
        self.sendMessage(START)

    def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
        #Here you get the messages pushed from the server
        self._received_msgs.append(msg)
        #If it is time to close the connection
        if self.close_condition(msg):
            self.damocle_sword.cancel()
            self.sendClose()

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        #Now it is the right time to check our test assertions
        self.assertion.callback(self._received_msgs)

class TestClientProtocolFactory(WebSocketClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, assertion, close_condition, timeout, **kwargs):
        WebSocketClientFactory.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.assertion = assertion
        self.close_condition = close_condition
        self.timeout = timeout
        #This parameter needs to be forced to None to not leave the reactor dirty
        self.openHandshakeTimeout = None

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        protocol = TestClientProtocol(self.assertion, self.close_condition, self.timeout)
        protocol.factory = self
        return protocol
```

### The trial based test

```
class WebSocketTest(TrialTest):

    def setUp(self):
        port = 8088
        factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:{}".format(port))
        factory.protocol = TestServerProtocol
        self.listening_port = listenWS(factory)
        self.factory, self.port = factory, port

    def tearDown(self):
        #cleaning up stuff otherwise the reactor complains
        self.listening_port.stopListening()

    def test_message_reception(self): 
        #This is the test assertion, we are testing that the messages received were 3
        def assertion(msgs):
            self.assertEquals(len(msgs), 3)

        #This class says when the connection with the server should be finalized. 
        #In this case the condition to close the connectionis for the client to get 3 messages
        class CommunicationHandler(object):
            msg_count = 0

            def close_condition(self, msg):
                self.msg_count += 1
                return self.msg_count == 3

        d = Deferred()
        d.addCallback(assertion)
        #Here we create the client...
        client_factory = TestClientProtocolFactory(d, CommunicationHandler().close_condition, 5, url="ws://localhost:{}".format(self.port))
        #...and we connect it to the server
        connectWS(client_factory)
        #returning the assertion as a deferred purely for demonstration
        return d
```

This is obviously just an example, but as you can see I did not have to mess around with `makeConnection` or any `transport` explicitly

Comment: This is a bad approach according to trial documentation and I wrote that I don't want to create dummy server. The thing is that what I used (`StringTransport`) is a special transport made for testing purposes. In actual app I use binary frames. Read this http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/trial.html#auto6. Especially this part *Testing protocols without the use of real network connections is both simple and recommended when testing Twisted code. Even though there are many tests in Twisted that use the network, most good tests don't*.

Comment: The point of my reply is to show you what you might do wrong in using the autobahn library, not to get inspiration for writing dummy servers or Trial testing strategies. The fact that you make use of low level functions in a wrong way got you to mess up with WebSocket state and mine is just an example (beyond the stupid echo approach) to show you how to use the library. If you'd share more details on the actual protocol, I might give you a more useful answer.

Comment: There are no more details. All I want is to create fake WebSocket connection and send data through it, just like StringTransport from proto_helpers does. Right now there is no such option as I can see.

Comment: I get your point about avoiding networks. It indeed is better to use a fully controllable stack and transport, but if you face problems in testing your protocol this way, you arguably might want to do the simplest thing that works, i.e. using network in your test.