# How to write TestCase for websockets?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahnws

I just want to write a TestCase for `WebSocketClientProtocol` in the setUp and tearDown I think I setup correctly the Server.

All I want is `test client connected to server and server send some message client will receive` that's it.

Below is the code I tried to make but I don't go further from here

```
class WebSocketTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:8000")
        self.listening_port = listenWS(factory)
        self.factory, self.port = factory, port

    def tearDown(self):
        self.listening_port.stopListening()

    def test_client_message(self):
        client_factory = TestClientProtocolFactory(
            url="ws://127.0.0.1:8000".format(self.port))
        connectWS(client_factory)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  Is an exception raised?  Does the test hang?  Can you manually connect to the test port manually (e.g. via telnet)?

Comment: @LexScarisbrick sorry I don't know how to ask. I created the web socket server inside the test case and using when test case running server send some message to client and client will get that message. But Why don't know where to look and how to receive the message when server send...

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14844253/6084928) will help.

Comment: @LexScarisbrick thanks I'll take look..