# How to implement Comet server side with Python?

Tags: python, comet

I once tried to implement Comet in PHP. Soon, I found that PHP is not suitable for Comet, since each HTTP request will occupy one process/thread. As a result, it doesn't scale well.

I just installed mod_python in my XAMPP. I thought it would be easy to implement Comet with Python asynchronous programming. But still cannot get a clue how to implement it.

Is there any idea how to implement Comet in mod_python?

Comment: I think you mean to say "Apache is not suitable for comet" and not "PHP is not suitable for comet"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I'm not async expert at all, I just investigated the topic once. 
IMHO if you're using XAMPP then you're loosing the posibility of doing long polling because Apache uses thread/processes (depending on configuration) for each request.

What you need, is non-blocking web server, like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), that allows splitting requests into two parts, of which the second one is fired on some event, but meanwhile server can accept subsequent inbound requests.

Example from [Tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation) /[license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)/:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http.fetch("http://friendfeed-api.com/v2/feed/bret",
               callback=self.async_callback(self.on_response))

    def on_response(self, response):
        if response.error: raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
        json = tornado.escape.json_decode(response.body)
        self.write("Fetched " + str(len(json["entries"])) + " entries "
                   "from the FriendFeed API")
        self.finish()
```

-- as far as I know this is not possible under Apache - in which fetch is regular part of request handler, which of course block until it's complete - so what you end with is frozen thread or process.

Another famous library for doing non-blocking services in Python is [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), but I don't know much about it, only that it also is able to help you in handling a lot of connections with only one thread/process.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Just want to confirm. Is it true that Apache stick one thread/process for each HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know (long time mod_wsgi + Django user) that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960969/python-comet-server), but the question asked is pretty similar and there seem to be some good answers there. HTH.