# How can I insert html code from outern url in django template?

Tags: python, html, django

I need something like file_get_contents in PHP. 
I kwnow it's some like:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

but how can I put it in django html template?

Thx for fast answers.

Comment: You don't put this in template because template does rendering, and this is data-pulling. So you do that in your view, assign result to template context, and then render it in template.

Comment: ok, I add this to view to var: tpldata['somecode']. now how can I put it into template?

Comment: Yes you can. Easiest way to render a template is `render_to_response` function in `django.shortcuts`. Variables in template are rendered like this: `{{ somevar|safe }}`. The `safe` keyword tells template-engine that this is html code and it is safe (it will not be escaped). Check django-template language documentation for more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/. Also have a look at builtin tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put that directly into django's html templating language. You might consider:

- Prefetching the html, store it somewhere and render it to the template.
- Use an ajax call, that triggers a view that does the crawling, then on success you insert your html in the DOM (this is blocking and slow at server-side).
- If you truly want this to be non-blocking, use a non-blocking server. See this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441533/how-to-implement-comet-server-side-with-python) as an example.