# Application in which I need Auto-update just like Gmail inbox,calendar Face-Book etc

Tags: jquery, python, google-apps

I have made application in which I have kept calendar. Now I need that if admin changes his calendar and if it is affected to user and if that user is currently looking that calendar then whatever changes Admin has done that should reflect to user without refreshing the page,
just like when email comes to Gmail then without refreshing we can see the inbox marked as unread...

So to implement that what should I do?

I am using J-query for user interface and Python as back-end?

Comment: a) To implement you need to start. b) Is `I am using J-query for user interface and Python as back-end?` really a question?

Answer (score 2):

go to [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

[Python Comet Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960969/python-comet-server) this thread contains info on a comet like server for python, this would give you the real time browser data push I think you are referring to. I believe gmail does it by using an iframe hack and a setinterval check using some javascript ajax call.