# What are some modern Comet servers written in Python?

Tags: python, twisted, comet, eventlet

I've built my application in python (using greenthreads from eventlent) and I was supposed to use Orbited as comet server to pass requests from user-end javascript code to my application.

Sadly, I found that Orbited is dead, site is down for a few weeks and it lack python 2.7 support.

Could you recommend some good replacements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Comet Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960969/python-comet-server)

Comment: it's outdated, as I said, Orbited is dead and seems like StreamHub doesn't work in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  seems that for now the best option is to use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), which offer simple and feature-rich programming interface both on server and client side. The python options are:

- [gevent-socketio](https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio)
- [SocketTornad.IO](https://github.com/SocketTornadIO/SocketTornad.IO)
- [socketIO-client](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client)

Answer (score 1):

You could build a comet server using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), [meinheld](http://meinheld.org/), [mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/), [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), or [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/), all of which have long-polling examples. This list isn't exhaustive. You could also consider using WebSockets instead, several have WebSocket examples as well.

Comment: but the reason why I've created this topic is that I'm not willing to create it by hand and looking for some out-the-box solution (which Orbited was)

Comment: @Andrew I think you are overestimating the complexity of writing a comet app. This answer has a [simple example of long-polling code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code/333884#333884). Also check out [tornado's chat example](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, but it seems that [CometD has a Twisted-based implementation](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/cometd-twisted/) of its protocol.

Answer (score -1):

http://meteorserver.org/

Probably that won't register as an answer as you are looking for a server written in Python. Still, I would recommend this efficient server written in Perl. After all, IMHO, as an out-of-the-box/off-the-shelf solution it's as good as any other Python-based server can get.