# Periodic Ajax POST calls versus COMET/Websocket Push

Tags: ajax, comet

On a site like Trello.com, I noticed in firebug console that it makes frequent and periodic Ajax POST calls to its server to retrieve new data from the database and update the dom as and when something new is available.

On the other hand, something like Facebook notifications seem to be implementing a COMET push mechanism.

What's the advantage and disadvantage of each approach and specifically, my question is why Trello.com uses a "pull" mechanism as I have always thought using such an approach (especially since it pings its server so frequently) as it seems like it is not a scalable solution - when more and more users sign up to use its services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer to Your Question

Your gut instinct is correct. Long-polling (aka comet) will be more efficient than straight up polling. And when available, websockets will be more efficient than long-polling. So why some companies use the "pull polling" is quite simply: they are out of date and need to put some time into updating their code base!

## Comparing Polling, Long-Polling (comet) and WebSockets

With traditional polling you will make the same request repeatedly, often parsing the response as JSON or stuffing the results into a DOM container as content. The frequency of this polling is not in any way tied to the frequency of the data updates. For example you could choose to poll every 3 seconds for new data, but maybe the data stays the same for 30 seconds at a time? In that case you are wasting HTTP requests, bandwidth, and server resources to process many totally useless HTTP requests (the 9 repeats of the same data before anything has actually changed).

With long polling (aka comet), we significantly reduce the waste. When your request goes out for the updated data, the server accepts the request but doesn't respond if there is no new changes, instead it holds the request open for 10, 20, 30, or 60 seconds or until some new data is ready and it can respond. Eventually the request will either timeout or the server will respond with an update. The idea here is that you won't be repeating the same data so often like in the 3 second polling above, but you still get very fast notification of new data as there is likely already an open request just waiting for the server to respond to.

You'll notice that long polling reduced the waste considerably, but there will still be the chance for some waste. 30-60 seconds is a common timeout period for long polling as many routers and gateways will shutdown hanging connections beyond that time anyway. So what if your data is actually changed every 15 minutes? Polling every 3 seconds would be *horribly inefficient*, but long-polling with timeouts at 60 seconds would still have some wasted round trips to the server.

Websockets is the next technology advancement that will allow a browser to open a connection with the server and keep it open for as long as it wants and deliver multiple messages or chunks of data via the same open websocket. The server can then send down updates exactly when new data is ready. The websocket connection is already established and waiting for data, so it is quick and efficient.

## Reality Check

The problem is that Websockets is still in its infancy. Only the very latest generation of browsers support it, if at all. The spec hasn't been fully ratified as of this posting, so implementations can vary from browser to browser. And of course your visitors may be using browsers a few years old. So unless you can control what browsers your visitors are using (say corporate intranet where IT can dictate the software on the workstations) you'll need a mechanism to abstract away this transport layer so that your code can use the best technique available for that particular visitor's browser.

There are other benefits to having an abstracted communications layer. For example what if you had 3 grid controls on your page all pull polling every 3 seconds, see the mess this would be? Now rolling your own long-polling implementation can clean this up some, but it would be even cooler if you aggregated the updates for all 3 of these tables into one long-polling request. That will again cut down on waste. If you have a small project, again you could roll your own, but there is a standard [Bayeux Protocol](http://cometd.org/documentation/bayeux) that many server push implementations follow. The Bayeux protocol automatically aggregates messages for delivery and then segregates messages out by "channel" (an arbitrary path-like string you as a developer use to direct your messages). Clients can listen on channels, and you can publish data on channels, the messages will get to all clients listening on the channel(s) you published to.

The number of server side server push tool kits available is growing quite fast these days as Push technology is becoming the next big thing. There are probably 20 or more working implementations of server push out there. Do your own search for "{Your favorite platform} comet implementation" as it will continue to change every few months I'm sure (and has been covered on stackoverflow before).

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive description of the differences between polling and long polling ('comet push') and here's an interesting one relating to your mention of `bayeux` protocol - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960969/python-comet-server